# for文で生成した文字列をタプルに格納する方法

Tags: python

初めて質問させていただきます。
for文で生成した文字列をタプルに格納し、辞書型と結び付けたいです。

```
factories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
shops = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

cost      = ( 8, 10, 12, 16, 20,
             12,  8,  6, 10, 16,
             18,  7,  4,  3,  4,
             12, 10, 12, 16, 20 )

for f in factories:
        for s in shops:
                root = f + s
                print(root)
```

文字列の生成までは終わったのですが...ここから先で躓いています><

[追記]
keyはroot, valueはcostにして、変数patternに代入したいです。
以下のようになるのが理想です

```
pattern = { 'A1': 8, 'A2': 10, 'A3': 12 ... D5: 20 }
```

お願いします。

Comment: 辞書(dict) の key はどちらになるのでしょうか？ cost でしょうか？それとも for で生成した文字列ですか？

Comment: 最終的な出力をどのようにしたいのかを明示してください。

Comment: @metorpolis さん、 コメントありがとうございます！keyがrootでvalueはcostですね。

Comment: @dosec さん、コメントありがとうございます！値を他の場所でも使用するので、変数に入れて出力したいです。よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一応ここまでしたいかを別にすれば dict で内包表記を使うこともできます．

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import product
factories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
shops = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

costs      = ( 8, 10, 12, 16, 20,
             12,  8,  6, 10, 16,
             18,  7,  4,  3,  4,
             12, 10, 12, 16, 20 )


d = {f+s : cost
         for ((f,s), cost) in zip(product(factories,shops), costs)}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

keyをroot、valrueをcostで辞書にしてみました
forでリストやタプルを作りたい場合は、リスト内包表記が便利です

```
import itertools
root = [''.join((x, y)) for x, y in itertools.product(factories, shops)]
dict(zip(root, cost))
```